# Substituting sour trahana for kashk

Tags: substitutions, soup, dairy, middle-eastern-cuisine

[Kashk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashk) (also Kishik) is a form of dried yogurt used all over the middle east and central Asia as an ingredient.  [Sour Trahana](https://www.dianekochilas.com/what-is-trahana/) is a second dried milk product used in Greece and the middle east. Where I live, I can purchase sour trahana, but not kashk.

How should I substitute trahana in recipes that call for kashk?  Say, for example, in a soup recipe [like ones that use kashk as a topping](https://www.thedeliciouscrescent.com/persian-noodle-soup-with-beans-and-herbs/), or ones that [use kashk as a base](https://zaatarandzaytoun.com/kishik-soup/)?  What adjustments should I make?

Comment: I'd never even heard of trahana, so I can't offer an answer; but one thought: Iranian kashk is very salty.  When you make ash reshteh, you need to be careful not to over-salt the soup, because the kashk will add so much salt on its own.  That link about sour trahana you provided didn't mention anything about its being salty - if it's not, that's one adjustment you'd need to make.

Comment: Yeah, sour trahana isn't that salty.

Comment: Your profile suggests that you are in San Francisco. Is it really impossible to find kashk there? There seem to be quite a number of Persian specialty stores. Do none of them sell kashk? At least some restaurants seem to have it, and one presumes you could by it from them in bulk. [This article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/food/2021/03/12/liquid-kashk-recipe/) notes that many Iranian stores sell it under the name of whey, as well as suggesting a recipe to make it at home.

Comment: Failing that, online ordering is probably an option. Here is [an example.](https://persianbasket.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=kashk)

Comment: Oh, wow, I need to update my profile.  Not in SF anymore.  Portland.  Checked out our couple of ME groceries, they don't have it.   Anyway, my question is not "how do I buy kashk" but "what's the substitution between these two very similar ingredients"?

Comment: @FuzzyChef if you *were* asking where to get kashk, it's a bit of a drive from Portland, but if you're ever in Boston, [Super Hero's](https://www.yelp.com/biz/super-heros-watertown) has kashk.  Arax, which is a couple blocks away might have it too.